# SSRS Chart Data Drill Through only returning only single row result

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I have a pie chart in my report that has count of Names in values and Sex (M or F) as category. I have a drill through report that has other demographics related to the name. I want to pass the data region the user clicked on to get relevant data in sub report. I used all the standard noms in setting the parameter and an action to the series to go to the new report.

ISSUE: When I pass the parameter (data region user clicked on i.e. the names) to the drill through report only single row is getting retreived. 
1. I set the query to use IN 
2. There is no value(0) being passed 
3. Multi value option is chckd.

Kindly help me to understand where im going wrong. Thanks,

Comment: I dont understand - why would you expect multiple values to be passed by clicking on a single value?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't define the sub-report data region by a list of names. I would define it by the category. In your case, it appears to be `Sex`. Set your sub-report query to take a `@Sex` parameter, and pass that value from the Pie Slice being clicked. Let me know if there is some detail you left out that invalidates this answer, and I'll update it accordingly.

**EDIT**
To group by a dynamic attribute, use a `@GroupBy` parameter in your query and pass it from the report. Your Query would look something like this:

```
select
    case @GroupByID
        when 1 then Sex
        when 2 then State
        when 3 then Age
    end GroupBy,
    count(*) Cnt
from YourTable
group by
    case @GroupByID
        when 1 then Sex
        when 2 then State
        when 3 then Age
    end
```

Then your detail sub-report would take two parameters, a `@GroupByID` and a `@GroupByFilter`. You would pass these from your chart with `@GroupByID = @GroupByID` and `@GroupByFilter = Fields!GroupBy.Label` Your SQL for the sub-report would be something like this:

```
select *
from YourTable
where
    (@GroupByID = 1 and Sex = @GroupByFilter) or
    (@GroupByID = 2 and State = @GroupByFilter) or
    (@GroupByID = 3 and Age = @GroupByFilter)
```

Comment: I understand that but there are more than 15 measures that i need to display common measures like demographics data. The tables are structured badly and i cant change its structure, have to work with wat I have got. If i have to pass specific measures parameter I have to create more than 15 subreports or 15 tablix under the same report I wanted to avoid that. So only. If there is a workaround kindly educate me if not I will continue with my solution. Thanks for ur time appreciate it.

Comment: You are quite welcome, I am happy to help :) I would try to get your chart data to return a single GroupBy column determined by a parameter with the relevant counts and then your detail sub-report to display all that data, but allow a parameter to pass any of the demographics using a GroupByID. If you update your question to include your query, I can help you fix it to accomplish this.